# Excel - Issue with using only ints to get range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

```
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim agentRange As Range

    Set agentRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet").Range(Range("S9").value, Range("T9").value)

    For Each cell In agentRange

        Dim col As Long
        col = cell.column

        Dim cellStart As Range
        ***cellStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet").Cells(3, col))***

       'Do Stuff

    Next cell
```

So I'm having problems with my cellStart assignment. When I attempt to use the code as written I'm receiving an error.

```
Run-time error '91'

Object Variable or With block variable not set
```

Comment: what `Range` are you tyring to get to `Set agentRange` ? if you add a line after this line of `Debug.Print agentRange.Address` , what do you get ?

Comment: That part returns the correct range. That particular statement lets you crop what chunk of the data you generate a report for. The range set is C1 to BN1. col then returns 3 as expected.

Comment: the in your error you mean `Set cellStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet").Cells(3, col))`, right ? you are missing the `Set` for setting the `Range`

Comment: @ShaiRado that was it. Thanks Much! You should make that an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is `cellStart` is a `Range`.

Therefore, you need to `Set` it with:

```
Set cellStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet").Cells(3, col)
```

*Note*: you have one "extra" closing bracket at the end, you have 2 `))` instead of just `)`